# Custom sort in Laravel Scout search (Algolia)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout

I'm using the Laravel Algolia package for my search, and I would like to tap into the sorting order before sending my results to the view. After searching for all products I would like to bump up all products that the user has in their favourites. And then finally paginate the results.

```php
$results = Product::search($search);
//Then I would like to do this:
$results = $results->sort(function($a, $b) {
  return $user->hasFavourite($a) < $user->hasFavourite($b) ? -1 : 1
});
return $results->paginate(48);
```

But I know this isn't allowed in the `Laravel\Scout\Builder` object that is returned from the `::search`, so I was wondering if there's a way around this?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have there? It's (presumably) a collection of elements, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @miken32 The `Builder` returned by `::search` with Laravel Scout does not have a `sort` function. I'd have to convert it to a `Collection` first to sort it, but then I lose the ability to `paginate`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I clarified in your question what `$results` is. Collections can be paged. See e.g. https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e

Answer (score 0):

### Add relationship in scout

As mentioned in this [blog post](https://serversideup.net/search-eloquent-relationships-with-laravel-scout-and-meilisearch/), you have to add the relationship to the model first! You can do it in any way you know better:

```php
public function userRanks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Favorties', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
```

### Searchable by relationship

Then You should make model [searchable](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scout#modifying-the-import-query) by that index:

```php
protected function makeAllSearchableUsing($query)
{
    return $query->with('userRanks');
}
```

### Make Sortable

Add created field to sortables! as mentioned in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scout#configuring-filterable-data-for-meilisearch):

```
'index-settings' => [
    Product::class => [
        'sortableAttributes' => ['userRanks']
    ],
],
```

### ReIndex(optional)

> If you already have records in your index, make sure that you re-index with Meilisearch.

If you don’t have a ton of data, you could flush and re-build the entire index using the following commands:

```
// Clear the index
php artisan scout:flush "App\Models\Product"

// Re-populate the index
php artisan scout:import "App\Models\Product"
```

### Replicas

Read the [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/sorting/how-to/sort-by-attribute/):

> By design, Algolia provides one ranking formula per index: when you want to provide different rankings for the same data you need to use different indices for each ranking. These additional indices are called replicas.

Based On docs this will help:

```php
$index->setSettings([
  'replicas' => [
    'virtual(products_virtual_price_desc)'
  ]
]);
$replica_index = $client->initIndex('products_virtual_price_desc');

$replica_index->setSettings([
  'customRanking' => [
    'desc(price)'
  ]
]);
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I'm not trying to sort by a custom property on the product itself, but rather based on the logged in user. And that information is not sent to Algolia, so that means that Algolia doesn't know about the property that I want to sort by.

Comment: @petrix how did you come up with the solution